# Adding primary key to some exising tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, for-loop, primary-key

I have a database with over 600 tables. Some of the tables have primary keys and some do not. How can I dynamically:
1. loop through all tables
2. select ones that do not have primary keys
3. add an auto incremented field
4. make this field the primary key

I would presume it would be a combination of the following:

```
USE MyDataBase; 
GO
-- List all tables without primary constraint
SELECT i.name AS IndexName, 
    OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
    COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
FROM sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 0
GO

-- add new auto incremented field
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD PK_ID BIGINT IDENTITY;
GO

-- create new primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (PK_ID);
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query, will exclude all tables that have either a primary key or an identity column, it will then add identity column and primary key on the remaining objects

```
DECLARE @PKScript AS VARCHAR(max) = '';
SELECT @PKScript += 
    '  ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(obj.SCHEMA_ID))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(obj.name) + 
                      ' ADD PK_ID BIGINT IDENTITY;' +
     ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(obj.SCHEMA_ID))+'.'+QUOTENAME(obj.name) + 
                     ' ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ID_' + obj.name+ ' PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (PK_ID) '
 FROM sys.objects obj
 WHERE object_id not in
     (select parent_object_id
      from sys.key_constraints 
      where type = 'PK'
      UNION
      Select object_id
      from sys.identity_columns
      )
      AND type = 'U'
--PRINT (@PKScript);
EXEC(@PKScript);
```

For the tables that already have identity column defined, you might use this query to set this identity column to be the primary key (because you can't have two identity columns on the same table)

```
DECLARE @PKScript2 VARCHAR(max)='';

SELECT @PKScript2 += ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(obj.SCHEMA_ID))+'.'+
       QUOTENAME(obj.name) + ' ADD CONSTRAINT PK_' + icol.name +'_'+ obj.name+
       ' PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (' + QUOTENAME(icol.name) + ')' + CHAR(13)
FROM sys.identity_columns icol INNER JOIN 
     sys.objects obj on icol.object_id= obj.object_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.key_constraints k
                  WHERE k.parent_object_id = obj.object_id
                        AND k.type = 'PK')
      AND obj.type = 'U'
--PRINT (@PKScript2);
EXEC(@PKScript2);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ala. I will try this. However, it seems like I would need to run a separate query for those tables with existing identity columns that do not have primary key?

Comment: @amindomeniko please see my updated answer to cover both scenarios. I even updated the first query to remove some un-necessary code.

Comment: for the first query, the where clause does not return anything. This means all tables have must have an identity key, which means they should fall in the second query. As for the second query, it runs and prints out the scripts but does not take action.

Comment: @amindomeniko Just realized that I missed the @ when I used PKScript2 in the select. It should work now.

Comment: this took care of all tables successfully but 10 of them. I realized these 10 tables have unique keys. Any idea why these would not fit in either of the scripts?

Comment: Very good catch @amindomeniko. Because I excluded all objects that have a key constraint and forgot to mention that it must be of type 'PK'. I just added this condition now in the inner query after the NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I just realized that I am encountering a new issue with regard to the solution above. I have to deal with tables that may not have unique keys but have unique indexes. How would I deal with those?